# I'm having trouble with the last 5 blank lines of coding. I'm new to python, can anyone walk me through it?

Tags: python

//How to show our time by
12-hour clock and by 24-hour clock?
//the first about is about normal clock conversion, i believe?

```
def main():

     in1 = input("Enter the Hour: ")

     num = 0 + eval(in1)     # eval() convert the input string into a number
    if (num <= 0) or (num >= 25):
      print(in1,'is out of range')
      return 0   #if it is over 25, print and terminate
    else:
      num1 = num % 12  #2%12 =2;

    if(num == 24):
      f12 = "MIDNIGHT"
    elif(num < 10):
      f12 = "0"+str(num1)+" AM" # 1-9, convert 1 to 01 
    elif(num > 12):
      f12 =  str(num1)+" PM"  # >12, convert 13 to 1
      #f12 =  str(num-12)+" PM"  # >12, convert 13 to 1
    elif num == 12:
      f12 = "NOON"
    else:
      f12 = str(num1)+" AM" # 10,11, 12
    print("Time", in1,  "using 12-hour clock: ",f12)

    if(num == 24):
       ________________________________
    elif(num == 12):
       ________________________________
    elif(num < 10):
       ________________________________
    else:
       ________________________________
    print("Time", in1,  "using 24-hour clock: ",f24)
    main()
```

I understand getting the 12 hour clock but the last 5 lines are about 
24     hour time conversion, I'm guessing? I have just started learning   python online and came across this question. If you could explain and break this down to me I'd really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

The first block of `if`s is handling the special cases for a 12 hour clock, e.g. is it `MIDNIGHT`, `NOON`, `AM / PM`. You are being asked to complete the special cases for a 24 hr clock and assign the result to the variable `f24`. I'm assuming `24: f24 = 'MIDNIGHT'`, `12: f24 = 'NOON'`, you don't need to do anything special for `> 12`, but if `< 10` you need to pad a `0` just like in the 12 hour clock.

There are much easier ways for doing this in python but this is instructional material that I assume is taking this approach for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of comments.

First, this isn't good code to emulate.
Second, if you aren't sure what's going on, run the program and see.  For a little script like this, it's no trouble.

Now to the code.

num is just the 24-hour clock hour that the user entered, converted to an int.  f12 is the equivalent time on a 12-hour clock, as a string.

num1 is the hour on a twelve-hour clock, computed by

```
num1 = num % 12
```

The % operator here gives remainder on division by 12, so 14 % 12 = 2.

```
if num == 24:
   f12 = "MIDNIGHT"
```

I assume this is clear.

```
elif(num < 10):
      f12 = "0"+str(num1)+" AM" # 1-9, convert 1 to 01
```

If the number is less than 10, the script places a "0" before the hour, and adds " AM" at the end, as indicated in the comment.  The `+` means string concatenation.

```
elif(num > 12):
  f12 =  str(num1)+" PM"  # >12, convert 13 to 1
```

In the afternoon, the time on the 24-hour is different, so we use num1 for the hour and concatenate " PM".  Note the space in the string " PM".  This is to avoid having the "PM" smack up against the hour. For some reason, the script isn't appending a 0 to one-digit hours in the afternoon. I suspect that is an oversight on the part of the author.

I imagine the rest of the code is clear by now.

This is not a good way to write the code.  It would be better to calculate the data you need, then have one block of code that did the output.  This would avoid that mistake (as I take it to be) with one-digit hours.

I recommend that you try cleaning up the code, now that you understand it.

Answer (score -1):

why reinvent the wheel?

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
print "12hr: %s" % (datetime.datetime.strftime(now,"%I:%M:%S %p"))
print "24hr: %s" % (datetime.datetime.strftime(now,"%H:%M:%S"))
```